# What sickness was carried by the CSS Texas in Sahara?

Tags: sahara

In the 2005 adventure film "Sahara", treasure hunter Dirk Pitt is tracking down a Confederate ironclad named the *CSS Texas*, believing it to have sailed up the Niger River to an unknown location. He speaks to a priest at Labbezanga and they find the following record from the time:

> Six days after the great storm, a dark ship rode without sails under
>   the banner of a single star. It was driven upriver, never to return,
>   bearing... death. It brought a sickness from here up to Gao, and bore
>   over 300 souls to heaven. It was believed a damnation from Allah.

At the same time, WHO doctor Eva Rojas is investigating a plague-like sickness originating in Mali. We later find that the sickness is being caused by

> illegal storage of toxic materials underneath a solar energy plant in Mali.

I haven't read the Clive Cussler novels, so I'm not familiar with the book version of events. Obviously the Texas wasn't carrying that same sickness, however.

**What was the nature of the sickness carried by the *CSS Texas*?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## An unnamed Tropical Disease

The novel and movie cover some of the same ground but differ in a number of ways.

> The ship, its contents and the mortal remains of its crew, they having succumbed to a **tropical disease**, are a century later discovered buried in an old, dried up riverbed of the Niger River.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Texas_(1865))</sup>

Comment: is it not something caused by anatagonist's power plant? something poisonous chemicals related?

Comment: Nope. This is hundreds of years before the toxic issues.